# Access Control Allow Origin header missing on Parse app Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, parse-platform

I am making a web application that requires downloading of many JSON files and store them in localStorage once in a while( maybe a month). I am using Parse.com as Backend as a Service. I hosted my JSON on Parse.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.18.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Parse.initialize("MY_APP_KEY", "MY_JS_KEY");
</script>

    <script>
        $.getJSON( "http://myappname.parseapp.com/1111.json", function( data ) {
            var items = [];
            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
            });

            $( "<ul/>", {
                "class": "my-new-list",
                html: items.join( "" )
            }).appendTo( "body" );
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error:

`Cross Origin Request Blocked: Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing`.

But when I open it in my browser, it opens fine.

Why doesn't it work? Is there any possible solution for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otherwise you can add `callback=?` to the url you are using as below which will get the `jsonp` type of data:

```
$.getJSON( "http://myappname.parseapp.com/1111.json?callback=?", function( data ) {
        var items = [];
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
        });

        $( "<ul/>", {
            "class": "my-new-list",
            html: items.join( "" )
        }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://myappname.parseapp.com/1111.json',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    crossDomain:true,
    success:function( data ) {
        var items = [];
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
        });

        $( "<ul/>", {
            "class": "my-new-list",
            html: items.join( "" )
        }).appendTo( "body" );
    },
    error:function(jqXHR,responseText,status){
     console.log(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

This is how you do it in `ajax`. If you face any issue check `console` as it will be `logged`

Comment: how about using `$.ajax` where you can control `return type` and `crossdomain` issues?

Comment: Can you write one for me? I have never used AJAX before. :/

Comment: @AkshayArora Updated my answer!! check and let me know!!

Comment: I get this error `Missing ; before statement` in my 1111.json file. But I checked this url on jsonlint.com and it says valid url

Comment: Actually now the issue is in your `json` file but even am getting valid `json` and now if you see `json` file is retrieved

Comment: @AkshayArora Check this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/p6w11v2v/)** I've changed the url and if you go to the `url` the format they have wrapped in `callback`. If possible make necessary changes to your `json` file as shown in the demo file